# class com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.WebElement in invisibilityOfElementLocated

Tags: java, selenium

I am doing a simple test - waiting for an element to disappear from the page `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator));`
and sometimes I get this error, it is quite random, it can occur once in 5-10 runs, or 3 times in a row.
The full error message

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.WebElement (com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap and org.openqa.selenium.WebElement are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Comment: How is `locator` defined as in `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator));`

Comment: By.xpath("xpath_locator")